# How to let another function resolve a jquery deferred, functional programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am just a beginner in JS and working on a frontend. I produced some working code, but it is giving me a hard time to maintain and expand it. I wanted to move over to functional programming as much as possible, but I can't wrap my head around how to handle my deferreds.

Working code (make a modal, ask for 2 parameters, and either move on with parameters, or close the modal and don't move on):

```
var defer = $.Deferred();

var modal = {
    class: 'modal-box',
    title: 'Action required',
    message: 'Please specify where to split:',
    choices: [{modePK: 0, mode: 'All', checked: true},
              {modePK: 1, mode: 'Right-most'},
             ]

    };

$('body').append($('<div id="overlay_visible">'));
$('body').append($(Mustache.render($("#modal-delimiter-template").html(), modal)));

$('body').on('click', '#delimiter-submit', function () {
    defer.resolve(true, $(this));
});

$('body').on('click', '#deny-forms', function () {
    defer.resolve(false, $(this));
});

defer.done(function (cancelled, caller) {
    if (!cancelled) { *do fancy stuff with the choice*} else { *close the modal*} });
```

In this example the deferred is resolved in the two functions that I attributed manually to the two buttons in the modal. Now I wanted to move over to something like this:

```
function buttonAccept() {
   $('body').on('click', '#delimiter-submit', function () {
        defer.resolve(true, $(this)); <- THIS ISN'T DEFINED
   });
}

function buttonCancel() {
    $('body').on('click', '#deny-forms', function () {
        defer.resolve(false, $(this));  <- THIS ISN'T DEFINED
   });
}

function showModal(modal, template, ...buttonFunctions) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('body').append($(Mustache.render($(template).html(), modal)));
    buttonFunctions.apply(this) <--- THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK
    }

function askUserDelimiterMode () {

    var modal = {
        class: 'modal-box',
        title: 'Action required',
        message: 'Please specify where to split:',
        choices: [{modePK: 0, mode: 'All', checked: true},
                  {modePK: 1, mode: 'Right-most'},
                 ]

        };

    var template = "#modal-delimiter-template"

    return showModal(modal, template, buttonAccept, buttonCancel)
};

askUserDelimiterMode().then(*do fancy stuff with the choice*);
```

The second code is already much clearer and I can reuse things, but idk how to pass the deferred to the buttonFunctions. The buttonFunctions use the ... operator as I might need an arbitrary number of buttons with different effects in my frontend. I'm an absolute beginner to this and I would be happy about any push into the right direction.

Comment: why don't you pass the defer variable to your buttonFunctions?

Comment: `buttonFunctions` is an array, it does not have an `apply` method. This approach doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Notice this has nothing to do with functional programming, it's still imperative. But yes, modularisation by putting common things in functions is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put them in different functions when they belong together. Of course you could simply pass the deferred object as an argument into them, but that's a bad practice - asynchronous functions should create, resolve and return their promises themselves.

```
function showModal(modal, template, ...buttons) {
    const defer = $.Deferred();
    $('body').append($(Mustache.render($(template).html(), modal)));
    for (const [i, selector] of buttons.entries()) {
        $('body').on('click', selector, function() {
            defer.resolve(i, $(this));
        });
    }
    return defer.promise();
}
function askUserDelimiterMode () {
    var modal = {
        class: 'modal-box',
        title: 'Action required',
        message: 'Please specify where to split:',
        choices: [
            {modePK: 0, mode: 'All', checked: true},
            {modePK: 1, mode: 'Right-most'},
        ]
    };
    return showModal(modal, '#modal-delimiter-template', '#deny-forms', '#delimiter-submit');
}

askUserDelimiterMode().then(/*do fancy stuff with the choice*/);
```